ROS launch not working for turtlebot
OS - Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
ROS version - Kinetic
Gazebo Version: 7.0.0
command working: roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch
commands not working:
                  roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch

                  roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch

Error: turtlebot_empty_world.launch is neither a launch file in package turtlebot_gazebo nor is turtlebot_gazebo a launch file name.
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
How can I solve this?

There's a few things that I can think of that might help troubleshoot your problem.
Following Turtlebot3's manual/tutorials (which I assume you're referencing but if not maybe it could be helpful!): https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/simulation/

Ensure that you've got all prerequisites. Some PC Setup instructions must be complete first: https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/quick-start/
note that you do not need to do the network configuration step or any steps after that if this is simulation only.
Ensure that you have performed catkin_make in your catkin workspace (usually it will be ~/catkin_ws if you have followed general tutorials on ROS). This I think is the most likely problem since your system isn't aware of the package or launch file you're referencing.
Ensure that you have exported some kind of TurtleBot model to your environment. The TurtleBot3 manuals suggest export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger for the empty world example.

